# Change text color based on the surrounding color in flutter using ThemeData

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a `ThemeData` defined as follow:

```
class VendorThemeData {
  static ThemeData get themeData {
    return ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Colors.purple,
      accentColor: Colors.orange,
      textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
            bodyText1: TextStyle(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(20, 51, 51, 1),
            ),
            bodyText2: TextStyle(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(20, 51, 51, 1),
            ),
            headline6: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

And I will use the `static get` in my `MaterialApp` widget:

```
MaterialApp(
        home: ...,
        theme: isVendorMode ? VendorThemeData.themeData : ClientThemeData.themeData,
        ....)
```

My question is how do I have flutter change the text color based on the surrounding color? For example:

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Menu overview",
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
```

[image]

I am using the `headline6` text theme here for the title text in my `appbar`, I can't change the text color if I want to use my custom theme, the only way is to declare it white in my `ThemeData`, but then all my other `headline6` will have a white color.

If I want the "Menu Overview" text to have a white color to contrast the background, is it possible for flutter to detect this is automatically change the text color for me?

Comment: why not just create another variable in textTheme and use it exclusively for title?

Comment: but I remember that is a way for flutter to figure this out because if you are using the built-in colors, the different shade will prompt flutter to use a white text and vice versa

Comment: I'm not really sure if there is anything that flutter does automatically. But you can have a look at [computeLuminance](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color/computeLuminance.html)

Answer (score 0):

Can `copyWith` solve your problem? It can overwrite the property locally.

```
Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
```